# O que são middlewares em NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, funções, express.js, middleware

O que são middlewares e qual a sua importância para a plataforma Node?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Middleware é todo o tipo de função que está entre um pedido HTTP e a resposta final que o servidor envia de volta para o cliente.

Por exemplo, usando Express.js,  um pedido GET simples teria esta código:

```
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

se quiseres fazer um log do tipo de request e do url de um `request` podes usar este middleware simples:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.method, req.url);
  next();
});
```

A função middleware tem 3 parametros, pedido, resposta e callback. Podes ter *n* middleware a processar um pedido HTTP, encadeados. Quando um middleware acaba de processar coloca-se no final do código `next();`, invocando assim a callback e o código continua a correr para o proximo middleware ou resposta final.

O middleware é portanto uma funcionalidade, funções que executam processos intermédios. Os exemplos mais comuns são interagir com a BD, ir buscar ficheiros estáticos, tratar de erros ou redirecionamentos.

Um exepmplo de encadeamento de "middlewares" poderia ser assim:

```
var express = require('express'), // chamar a app e dar configurações minimas
    app = express.createServer(),                                                                                                                                                 
    port = 1337;
 
function middleHandler(req, res, next) {
    // tratar erros
    var err = req.body.foo == null;
    if (!err) next();
    else res.send("a variavel foo não tem dados!");
}
 
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // escrever na BD
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));                                                                                                             
    next();
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // outros processos                                                                                                            
    next();
});
 
app.get('/', middleHandler, function (req, res) {
    console.log(ultimo passo);
    res.send("Obrigado pelo seu registo!");
});
 
app.listen(port);  // iniciar o servidor
console.log('start server');
```

Repara que neste exemplo em cima o `app.get` tem um middleware como argumento. Podes usar middleware encadeados também dessa maneira. Aqui fica um exemplo real:

```
app.get('/', githubEvents, twitter, getLatestBlog, function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'MooTools',
        site: 'mootools',
        lastBlogPost: res.locals.lastBlogPost,
        tweetFeed: res.locals.twitter
    });
});
```

Este é um [exemplo que usamos no site do MooTools](https://github.com/mootools/website/blob/master/index.js#L85-L106) para carregar os post do Twitter, Blog e Github para carregar o `res` com as variáveis que a página precisa para ser processada.

**Nota:** Se usare `app.use` esse middleware vai ser chamado em **todos** os `request`. Se quiseres ser mais específico para por exemplo requests GET podes usar como nos exemplos em cima `app.get('caminho', middleware1, middlware2, etc, function(){ ...`

### Sugestão de leitura

- [Documentação Express.js sobre e tipos comums de middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) <sup>(em Inglês)</sup>

Comment: @nbro eu respondi com foco no express porque a pergunta tem a tag _expressjs_. Eu uso frequentemente middlewares no node, mesmo sem ser no express. Posso dar um exemplo mais logo então.

Answer (score 8):

Quando você cria uma rota em sua aplicação web você libera uma área de sua aplicação para que usuários acessem via browser ou outras aplicações acessem através de algum framework http client.
Quando essa rota é acessada, dois objetos principais surgem no callback dessa função, eles são:

```
**request**: ele é responsável por carregar dados da requisição que esta sendo realizada, geralmente vem com dados do cliente e algums parâmetros de input, como querystrings, parâmetros de rotas e body de um formulário. Em resumo, este objeto contém diversos dados do cliente.
**response**: este objeto permite que o servidor envie uma resposta para o cliente que realizou uma requisição. Aqui você pode enviar um html, json, dados via header, redirecionar a resposta para uma outra requisição, em geral este é um objeto focado em dar uma resposta para o cliente.
```

Os middlewares são funções que podem tratar os inputs e outputs das rotas antes e ou depois que uma rota é processada, ou seja, você pode criar um middleware que intercepta e verificar se uma requisição esta enviando um header específico e que caso o mesmo não esteja enviando o header ela retorne uma tela de erro para o usuário, negando a requisição de acessar uma determinada rota da aplicação, neste caso você criou e inejtou um middleware que trata uma pré-requisição. Você também pode criar um middleware que no final de cada resposta de uma rota, retorne também um header com metadados da resposta, por exemplo, headers de paginação de dados. Neste caso estamos criando um middleware de pós-requisição. Não há limites ao injetar middlewares, você pode criar e configurar N middlewares em sua aplicação, porém é sempre bom entender o que são cada middlewares e principalmente a ordem que cada middleware é injetado afeta no processamento de uma rota, ou seja, caso você injete middlewares em uma ordem errada, como efeito colateral sua aplicação pode responder ou até mesmo não processar corretamente suas rotas, por isso é extremamente importante entender o que cada middleware faz e em que ordem injetá-los.

Comment: Olá, Vanderson. Um middleware para ter o funcionamento semelhante aos dos filtros em uma aplicação JEE. Esta minha impressão está correta?

Comment: Não conheço JEE, o que posso te falar é que um Middleware é o tipo de função que está entre um request e um response. Assim como o @Sergio disse no exemplo.